# How to post the url and picture in wall after users clicks like or recomment button?

Tags: facebook

I want to post the url and picture in wall after users clicks like or recomment button. Please suggest if this is possible.

Comment: Ya i solved it by event.subscribe method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by event.subscribe method